# JQuery UI: Get ID of source element in drag'n'dop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am impelemnting a drag'n'drop where you can drag users to a role. I know how I get the user ID and the target role ID but I do not know how to get the role ID where the user is dragged FROM!

```
<div id="role_1" class="role">
    <h5>Administrator</h5>
    <ul class="users">
        <li id="user_1">Foo</li>
        <li id="user_2">Bar</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="role_2" class="role">
    <h5>Member</h5>
    <ul class="users">
        <li id="user_1337">Baz</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Get roles and users lists
    var $templates = $(".role"),
        $users = $(".users");

    // let the user items be draggable
    $("li", $users).draggable({
        revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
    });

    // let the roles be droppable, accepting the user items
    $templates.droppable({
        accept: ".users > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $uid = ui.draggable.attr("id"),
                $targetRid = $(this).attr("id"),
                $sourceRid = ???;
                // snip
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook the [`start` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start), and get the closest `.role`:

```
$("li", $users).draggable({
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    start: function() {
        var role = $(this).closest(".role").attr("id");
        // Here, role is either the id or undefined if no role could be found
    }
});
```

If you need that information when it's *dropped*, you could store it on the element using [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) in the `start` event and then retrieve it when dropped.

Comment: Thanks that gave me the hint I needed... I just did `ui.draggable.closest(".role").attr("id")` in the droppable's drop event ;)

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo: Ah, yes, of course. Nice one! Because that's so different from my answer, you might want to post it as your own answer and (in two day's time) accept it. That's perfectly fine here on SO. Your call, though, of course. In any case, glad to have helped!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, may I ask you to take a look at a jQuery  draggable and droppable related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498364/jquery-drag-and-drop-simulation-does-not-work-for-the-last-draggable ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to remember this id when you start the drag event:

```
var srcId;
$("li", $users).draggable({
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        srcId = $(this).closest(".role").attr('id');
    }
});
```